# AWS route 53 won't validate my DNS certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I have the following aws Cloud formation script. It is supposed to wire up some components of a webapp I have been working on. It seems to be stuck on some cert validation. The 2 certs that where validated though email were validated just find. I can't seem to figure out how to get the [www.congresscritters.org](http://www.congresscritters.org) cert to validate. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  BaseHostedZone:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::HostedZone'
    Properties:
      Name: congresscritters.org.

  WebCert:
    Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
    Properties:
      DomainName: www.congresscritters.org
      ValidationMethod: DNS
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: www.congresscritters.org
          HostedZoneId: !Ref BaseHostedZone
      SubjectAlternativeNames:
        - congresscritters.org

  WebDistribution:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Aliases:
          - www.congresscritters.org
        DefaultRootObject: index.html
        Origins:
          - DomainName: congress-critters-web-ui-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
            Id: S3Origin
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: ''
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          AllowedMethods: ['GET', 'HEAD']
          TargetOriginId: S3Origin
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          Compress: true
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: false
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !Ref WebCert
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2

  BaseRecordSetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup'
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref BaseHostedZone
      RecordSets:
        - Name: www.congresscritters.org
          Type: A
          AliasTarget:
            HostedZoneId: !GetAtt WebDistribution.DomainName
            DNSName: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2 # Fixed value for CloudFront
          Comment: Website domain record

  APICert:
    Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
    Properties:
      DomainName: api.congresscritters.org
      ValidationMethod: EMAIL

  APIDevCert:
    Type: 'AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate'
    Properties:
      DomainName: api-dev.congresscritters.org
      ValidationMethod: EMAIL

  APIRecordSet:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref BaseHostedZone
      Name: api.congresscritters.org
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: 7wqzggw1za.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
        HostedZoneId: Z1UJRXOUMOOFQ8 # Fixed value for API Gateway
      Comment: API domain record

  APIDevRecordSet:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSet'
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref BaseHostedZone
      Name: api-dev.congresscritters.org
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: orb9e3jc05.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
        HostedZoneId: Z1UJRXOUMOOFQ8 # Fixed value for API Gateway
      Comment: API dev domain record
```

I have tried checking the various web controls on aws management console as well as reading there documentation.

Comment: The HostedZone is being created with your stack meaning that your NS (NameServers) will be created at the time of deployment. You need to make sure that your domain is updated with these NS servers in order for AWS to verify your domain via DNS.

Also, it is worth while to check that the record for validation are being create when you deploy the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set `ValidationMethod: EMAIL`, you have to check the email associated with the domain and verify the SSL cert using the email that you got from the AWS. Alternatively, use `DNS` validation method.